# Does (matrix) t-distribution have a conjugate prior?

Tags: bayesian, covariance, t-distribution

If my data Y follows [matrix T-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_t-distribution), i.e. $ Y \sim T_{n,p}(\nu,0,\Sigma,\Phi)$, can I find an appropriate prior for $\Phi$ such that its posterior is in closed form? Inverse Wishart distribution is the standard prior for modelling covariance however it's not conjugate with t-distributed likelihood.

I could use Laplace transformation to approximate the likelihood to be normal distributed, but if $\nu$ is too small it wouldn't be a good approximation...